# Timer.schedule different in Activity and BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

I schedule a timeatsk twice in activity(click the button twice),like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.btn_timer:
            addTimer();
            break;
    }
}
private void addTimer(){
    Log.e("----","------"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    if(timerTask == null){
        timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                timerCount++;
                Log.e("----","------=="+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                Log.e("------","------"+timerCount);
            }
        };
    }
    if(timer == null){
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(timerTask,1000,1000);
    }
}
```

result is :

[the right result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCqCM.png)

but I schedue the same task in BroadcastReceiver twice(click the button twice):
inActivity:

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.btn_timer:
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction("timer");
            this.sendBroadcast(intent);
            break;
    }
}
```

in broadcastReceiver:`
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        addTimer();
    }

```
private void addTimer(){
    Log.e("----",Thread.currentThread().getName());
    if(timerTask == null){
        timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                timerCount++;
                Log.e("----","------=="+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                Log.e("------","------"+timerCount);
            }
        };
    }
    if(timer == null){
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(timerTask,1000,1000);
    }
}`
```

but the result is 
[in two thread!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Bw1a.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is that you only have one instance of your Activity and so the second time you call `addTimer()`, `timerTask` and `timer` are non-null (because you already assigned them on the first click). Thus you only have a single timer.

Each time you send a broadcast a new broadcast receiver instance is created. Each instance will create it's own `timerTask` and `timer` (because they are null). Thus you will end up with multiple timers.

What are you actually trying to achieve with these timers?

Comment: I use the timers to count the seconds how long I play the video and report the seconds to the service.The video will stop and start many times,so should send more than one broadcast.How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Then you should just send the seconds to the service, not start a timer in the service. Why do you need a timer? Why don't you simply record the start time in a `Date` variable, and then calculate how many seconds the video has ben playing when it stops.

Comment: I have mutliple intent received within a fraction of 20 milliseconds inside onReceive. I need to add the intents to the list within a specified time. How can I do this?